# Cuda patches: install all or install latest?

Tags: cuda

There are several patches for Cuda v9.0

Should I install the latest patch or install all of the patches?

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a fully patched/updated CUDA 9.0, you should install all of them.

Comment: I think this applies to previous CUDA versions which have had patch downloads as well.